# pandas.read_json() not working as expected

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have written a python script that is supposed to form the csv from reading a json file. The json file is actually a line json, *i.e.* each line represents a json object. In my json file, each line has a key and a value. I need to read the value and form the csv from it. The sample json file is:

```
{"30b26e96052f7e4cda0fe2eff99d128ab2689cfee8637c0f50e540fae811c1b9": "{\"0\": \"440899\", \"1\": \"440900\", \"-1\": \"440898\"}"}
{"669b10aa7c547109650e12f9904152e74c52d55c0a6d6c66fe1ea7b0b37a4ba7": "{\"0\": \"440900\", \"1\": \"440901\", \"-1\": \"440899\"}"}
{"1e13e07b8484e730997fbe516f1e0adf94729dbb30c2e92dfbdb9839c6e4e434": "{\"0\": \"440901\", \"1\": \"440902\", \"-1\": \"440900\"}"}
```

Now, my code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import json


chunks = pd.read_json(
    "test.json",
    chunksize=100,
    lines=True,
)

for df in chunks:
    df = df.to_dict(orient='records')
    for row in df:
        print(row)
```

The output that I am looking for is

`{\"0\": \"440899\", \"1\": \"440900\", \"-1\": \"440898\"}`

This means that I want to read the value, the value itself is in json format where we have key, value pairs. My aim is to write such jsons in the csv file like:

```
0,1,-1
440899, 440900, 440898
..., ..., ...
```

What I am getting right now is totally confusing:

```
{'1e13e07b8484e730997fbe516f1e0adf94729dbb30c2e92dfbdb9839c6e4e434': nan, '30b26e96052f7e4cda0fe2eff99d128ab2689cfee8637c0f50e540fae811c1b9': '{"0": "440899", "1": "440900", "-1": "440898"}', '3533a5d915469b16e04c10587c1a56ff5b0a6e16e2de3ae9873ad0e5b772c10c': nan, '573a0044e9315d4d598019f8bde1ceb93eed42f6c078f2cf9769e9c7a53fd9b6': nan, '669b10aa7c547109650e12f9904152e74c52d55c0a6d6c66fe1ea7b0b37a4ba7': nan, 'a5d172be131b5ff72d621a845f5d501d5d78352a3d52b8a86af88912824d4bd9': nan, 'e41d5c4ca5ae85908cac2d8a665d1292ba6a6f98dd720651300ea9f893fb53ae': nan, 'f825fbd436b2533dc3473cda15c304c9c79a108d2e59d18ec54fc9706966536b': nan}
{'1e13e07b8484e730997fbe516f1e0adf94729dbb30c2e92dfbdb9839c6e4e434': nan, '30b26e96052f7e4cda0fe2eff99d128ab2689cfee8637c0f50e540fae811c1b9': nan, '3533a5d915469b16e04c10587c1a56ff5b0a6e16e2de3ae9873ad0e5b772c10c': nan, '573a0044e9315d4d598019f8bde1ceb93eed42f6c078f2cf9769e9c7a53fd9b6': nan, '669b10aa7c547109650e12f9904152e74c52d55c0a6d6c66fe1ea7b0b37a4ba7': '{"0": "440900", "1": "440901", "-1": "440899"}', 'a5d172be131b5ff72d621a845f5d501d5d78352a3d52b8a86af88912824d4bd9': nan, 'e41d5c4ca5ae85908cac2d8a665d1292ba6a6f98dd720651300ea9f893fb53ae': nan, 'f825fbd436b2533dc3473cda15c304c9c79a108d2e59d18ec54fc9706966536b': nan}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It thinks your keys are the column names. Your json looks a bit odd, it may be easier to restructure it like

```
{"id": "30b26e96052f7e4cda0fe2eff99d128ab2689cfee8637c0f50e540fae811c1b9", "0": "440899", "1": "440900", "-1": "440898"}
```

or maybe

```
{"id": "30b26e96052f7e4cda0fe2eff99d128ab2689cfee8637c0f50e540fae811c1b9", "data": "{\"0\": \"440899\", \"1\": \"440900\", \"-1\": \"440898\"}"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that each line of your json file contains a JSON object with one key and one value and that value is a *string* containing a JSON representation of an object.
Here is a function that takes a path to a file in your format and returns a data frame of the form you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

def load_file(file_path):
    lines = []

    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            obj = json.loads(line)
            for k, v in obj.items():
                record = json.loads(v)
            lines.append(record)
    return pd.DataFrame(lines)
```

Running this on a file containing your example input I get the DataFrame

```
>>print(load_file("test.json"))
        -1       0       1
0   440898  440899  440900
1   440899  440900  440901
2   440900  440901  440902
```

Calling to_csv on this dataframe will give you the csv file you specified.